# isprint('\t') evaluates to true (64) with /MD compiler option

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have an unexpected result for the [`isprint`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isprint/) function under Visual Studio 2017. Given the following program

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i += 1) {
    printf("isprint(0x%x aka '%c') = %s (%d)\n", i, (char)i,
           isprint((char)i) ? "yes" : "no", isprint((char)i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

compiled and executed using

```
cl /MD isprint.c /Feisprint.exe && isprint.exe
```

returns

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26433 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

isprint.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.14.26433.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:isprint.exe
isprint.obj
isprint(0x0 aka ' ') = no (0)
isprint(0x1 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x2 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x3 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x4 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x5 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x6 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x7 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x8 aka ') = no (0)
isprint(0x9 aka '       ') = yes (64)
isprint(0xa aka '
') = no (0)
isprint(0xb aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0xc aka '') = no (0)
') = no (0) aka '
isprint(0xe aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0xf aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x10 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x11 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x12 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x13 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x14 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x15 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x16 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x17 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x18 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x19 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1a aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1b aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1c aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1d aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1e aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1f aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x20 aka ' ') = yes (64)
isprint(0x21 aka '!') = yes (16)
isprint(0x22 aka '"') = yes (16)
isprint(0x23 aka '#') = yes (16)
isprint(0x24 aka '$') = yes (16)
isprint(0x25 aka '%') = yes (16)
isprint(0x26 aka '&') = yes (16)
isprint(0x27 aka ''') = yes (16)
isprint(0x28 aka '(') = yes (16)
isprint(0x29 aka ')') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2a aka '*') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2b aka '+') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2c aka ',') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2d aka '-') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2e aka '.') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2f aka '/') = yes (16)
isprint(0x30 aka '0') = yes (4)
isprint(0x31 aka '1') = yes (4)
isprint(0x32 aka '2') = yes (4)
isprint(0x33 aka '3') = yes (4)
isprint(0x34 aka '4') = yes (4)
isprint(0x35 aka '5') = yes (4)
isprint(0x36 aka '6') = yes (4)
isprint(0x37 aka '7') = yes (4)
isprint(0x38 aka '8') = yes (4)
isprint(0x39 aka '9') = yes (4)
isprint(0x3a aka ':') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3b aka ';') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3c aka '<') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3d aka '=') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3e aka '>') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3f aka '?') = yes (16)
isprint(0x40 aka '@') = yes (16)
isprint(0x41 aka 'A') = yes (1)
isprint(0x42 aka 'B') = yes (1)
isprint(0x43 aka 'C') = yes (1)
isprint(0x44 aka 'D') = yes (1)
isprint(0x45 aka 'E') = yes (1)
isprint(0x46 aka 'F') = yes (1)
isprint(0x47 aka 'G') = yes (1)
isprint(0x48 aka 'H') = yes (1)
isprint(0x49 aka 'I') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4a aka 'J') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4b aka 'K') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4c aka 'L') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4d aka 'M') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4e aka 'N') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4f aka 'O') = yes (1)
isprint(0x50 aka 'P') = yes (1)
isprint(0x51 aka 'Q') = yes (1)
isprint(0x52 aka 'R') = yes (1)
isprint(0x53 aka 'S') = yes (1)
isprint(0x54 aka 'T') = yes (1)
isprint(0x55 aka 'U') = yes (1)
isprint(0x56 aka 'V') = yes (1)
isprint(0x57 aka 'W') = yes (1)
isprint(0x58 aka 'X') = yes (1)
isprint(0x59 aka 'Y') = yes (1)
isprint(0x5a aka 'Z') = yes (1)
isprint(0x5b aka '[') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5c aka '\') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5d aka ']') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5e aka '^') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5f aka '_') = yes (16)
isprint(0x60 aka '`') = yes (16)
isprint(0x61 aka 'a') = yes (2)
isprint(0x62 aka 'b') = yes (2)
isprint(0x63 aka 'c') = yes (2)
isprint(0x64 aka 'd') = yes (2)
isprint(0x65 aka 'e') = yes (2)
isprint(0x66 aka 'f') = yes (2)
isprint(0x67 aka 'g') = yes (2)
isprint(0x68 aka 'h') = yes (2)
isprint(0x69 aka 'i') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6a aka 'j') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6b aka 'k') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6c aka 'l') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6d aka 'm') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6e aka 'n') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6f aka 'o') = yes (2)
isprint(0x70 aka 'p') = yes (2)
isprint(0x71 aka 'q') = yes (2)
isprint(0x72 aka 'r') = yes (2)
isprint(0x73 aka 's') = yes (2)
isprint(0x74 aka 't') = yes (2)
isprint(0x75 aka 'u') = yes (2)
isprint(0x76 aka 'v') = yes (2)
isprint(0x77 aka 'w') = yes (2)
isprint(0x78 aka 'x') = yes (2)
isprint(0x79 aka 'y') = yes (2)
isprint(0x7a aka 'z') = yes (2)
isprint(0x7b aka '{') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7c aka '|') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7d aka '}') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7e aka '~') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7f aka '') = no (0)
```

The problem is that it returns true (64) for the tabulator character (`'\t'`). However, when compiled without the `/MD` compiler option or some other runtime library version such as

```
cl /MDd isprint.c /Feisprint.exe && isprint.exe
```

the result is

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26433 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

isprint.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.14.26433.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:isprint.exe
isprint.obj
isprint(0x0 aka ' ') = no (0)
isprint(0x1 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x2 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x3 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x4 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x5 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x6 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x7 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x8 aka ') = no (0)
isprint(0x9 aka '       ') = no (0)
isprint(0xa aka '
') = no (0)
isprint(0xb aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0xc aka '') = no (0)
') = no (0) aka '
isprint(0xe aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0xf aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x10 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x11 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x12 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x13 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x14 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x15 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x16 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x17 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x18 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x19 aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1a aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1b aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1c aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1d aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1e aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x1f aka '') = no (0)
isprint(0x20 aka ' ') = yes (64)
isprint(0x21 aka '!') = yes (16)
isprint(0x22 aka '"') = yes (16)
isprint(0x23 aka '#') = yes (16)
isprint(0x24 aka '$') = yes (16)
isprint(0x25 aka '%') = yes (16)
isprint(0x26 aka '&') = yes (16)
isprint(0x27 aka ''') = yes (16)
isprint(0x28 aka '(') = yes (16)
isprint(0x29 aka ')') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2a aka '*') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2b aka '+') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2c aka ',') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2d aka '-') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2e aka '.') = yes (16)
isprint(0x2f aka '/') = yes (16)
isprint(0x30 aka '0') = yes (4)
isprint(0x31 aka '1') = yes (4)
isprint(0x32 aka '2') = yes (4)
isprint(0x33 aka '3') = yes (4)
isprint(0x34 aka '4') = yes (4)
isprint(0x35 aka '5') = yes (4)
isprint(0x36 aka '6') = yes (4)
isprint(0x37 aka '7') = yes (4)
isprint(0x38 aka '8') = yes (4)
isprint(0x39 aka '9') = yes (4)
isprint(0x3a aka ':') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3b aka ';') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3c aka '<') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3d aka '=') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3e aka '>') = yes (16)
isprint(0x3f aka '?') = yes (16)
isprint(0x40 aka '@') = yes (16)
isprint(0x41 aka 'A') = yes (1)
isprint(0x42 aka 'B') = yes (1)
isprint(0x43 aka 'C') = yes (1)
isprint(0x44 aka 'D') = yes (1)
isprint(0x45 aka 'E') = yes (1)
isprint(0x46 aka 'F') = yes (1)
isprint(0x47 aka 'G') = yes (1)
isprint(0x48 aka 'H') = yes (1)
isprint(0x49 aka 'I') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4a aka 'J') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4b aka 'K') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4c aka 'L') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4d aka 'M') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4e aka 'N') = yes (1)
isprint(0x4f aka 'O') = yes (1)
isprint(0x50 aka 'P') = yes (1)
isprint(0x51 aka 'Q') = yes (1)
isprint(0x52 aka 'R') = yes (1)
isprint(0x53 aka 'S') = yes (1)
isprint(0x54 aka 'T') = yes (1)
isprint(0x55 aka 'U') = yes (1)
isprint(0x56 aka 'V') = yes (1)
isprint(0x57 aka 'W') = yes (1)
isprint(0x58 aka 'X') = yes (1)
isprint(0x59 aka 'Y') = yes (1)
isprint(0x5a aka 'Z') = yes (1)
isprint(0x5b aka '[') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5c aka '\') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5d aka ']') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5e aka '^') = yes (16)
isprint(0x5f aka '_') = yes (16)
isprint(0x60 aka '`') = yes (16)
isprint(0x61 aka 'a') = yes (2)
isprint(0x62 aka 'b') = yes (2)
isprint(0x63 aka 'c') = yes (2)
isprint(0x64 aka 'd') = yes (2)
isprint(0x65 aka 'e') = yes (2)
isprint(0x66 aka 'f') = yes (2)
isprint(0x67 aka 'g') = yes (2)
isprint(0x68 aka 'h') = yes (2)
isprint(0x69 aka 'i') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6a aka 'j') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6b aka 'k') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6c aka 'l') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6d aka 'm') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6e aka 'n') = yes (2)
isprint(0x6f aka 'o') = yes (2)
isprint(0x70 aka 'p') = yes (2)
isprint(0x71 aka 'q') = yes (2)
isprint(0x72 aka 'r') = yes (2)
isprint(0x73 aka 's') = yes (2)
isprint(0x74 aka 't') = yes (2)
isprint(0x75 aka 'u') = yes (2)
isprint(0x76 aka 'v') = yes (2)
isprint(0x77 aka 'w') = yes (2)
isprint(0x78 aka 'x') = yes (2)
isprint(0x79 aka 'y') = yes (2)
isprint(0x7a aka 'z') = yes (2)
isprint(0x7b aka '{') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7c aka '|') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7d aka '}') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7e aka '~') = yes (16)
isprint(0x7f aka '') = no (0)
```

What is going on here? In noticed the change in my application about two weeks ago. Could this be caused by some Windows or Visual Studio update? I checked that the thread locale is the same in both cases.

Windows 10 build 17134.165

Comment: What makes you think that a tab is not printable?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the text in C11 5.2.2 seems to suggest that `\t` should not be a printing character , although it is not particularly clear

Comment: @Basile According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isprint/ tab is not a "printable" character. It is also gcc's behaviour.

Comment: Seems to be already reported as a bug https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7416, Windows isprint calls iswprint which seems to be broken.

Comment: Reported to Microsoft as https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/297085/changing-result-of-isspacet.html

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5 with any combination of Release/Debug/x64/x86.

Comment: Look at the Microsoft soure code and you'll see that there is a lot of locale stuff involved, I bet it is somewhat linked to locale stuff.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It gets a table stored in TLS an looks up the character in there. GetThreadLocale() was 2057 in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

@Meinersbur thank you for reporting this.  I was tearing my hair out trying to understand the difference since I was only seeing it on our build machine and not on my workstation.

For the sake of others coming here, the response from Microsoft (see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/297085/changing-result-of-isspacet.html) was:

> Tab being reported as a print character by isprint() is a regression in the Universal C Runtime that started appearing with the update KB4338819. It will be fixed in a future servicing update, as well as will be fixed in the next major version of Windows.
>
> The issue isn't related to /MD or /MDd settings. When building with /MD, the Universal C Runtime will be provided by the OS version in System32, which will change with your OS version. When building with /MDd, you will receive the debug version which ships with the Windows SDK and Visual Studio and you will use the most recent version you have installed.
>
> If you wish to have the same behavior as you saw in debug mode on all OSes, you can statically link the C Runtime by building with /MT.
>
> Hope this helps!
>
> Steve Wishnousky
> Software Engineer II - Visual C++ Libraries

Answer (score 1):

According to C11 7.4,

> The term *printing character* refers to a member of a locale-specific set of characters, each of which occupies one printing position on a display device;

Since a tab usually occupies several printing positions, it seems to me that this is saying that `\t` should NOT be a printing character.

The text in 5.2.2 (Character display semantics) seems to back this up, describing `\t` as a *nongraphic character*.

---

My interpretation is that the behaviour is non-conforming for `isprint('\t')` to be non-zero, as in your first example.

However I can see someone arguing that the standard is unclear and the behaviour should be defined by the locale;  and possible the change of compiler switches selects a different locale (?)

You could submit a bug report; then the compiler support people will either acknowledge it or advise why their compiler does this.

---

NB. The argument to `isprint` is supposed to be an integer value in the range `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`. So you should be writing `isprint(i)` rather than `isprint((char)i)`.  This is moot to your program as written since you restrict `i` to a subset of the correct range; however it would be incorrect if you let `i` exceed `127`.

Comment: On my Linux/Debian/Sid `isprint('\t')` is false

Comment: My question is more about the different behaviour between the runtimes than whether tab is a printable character. IMHO different behaviour in release and debug builds is very undesirable.

Comment: @Meinersbur I would suggest filing a bug report and thereby getting feedback from the compiler vendor. It's probably a bug, but perhaps they might offer some kind of justification to do with locales

Comment: For what it's worth, Posix allows the tab character (and other whitespace characters) to be included in the **print** category for locales other than the Posix (or C) locale. See Note 2 to the chart in [XBD 7.3.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) where it says "Other **space** or **blank** characters can be classified as any of **punct**, **graph**, or **print**." For example, one could imagine a locale in which the tab character always rendered as a single character (because of a locale-specific columnisation algorithm).

Comment: Of course, that's not really relevant to this question. A debug build should start in the C locale, just like a release build, and in the C locale a tab is not in **print**.